# Opengl blending and lighting in Libgdx

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, lighting

Ok, so I am trying to add ligting to my game but am having some problems in open gl using blending.

What I am trying to do, is cover the whole screen with a black square. Then, cut holes in it by applying another shape over it with a lower alpha level.

```
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA);
Gdx.gl20.glBlendEquation(GL.GL_FUNC_SUBTRACT);
woods.shapes.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    woods.shapes.setColor(255, 255, 255, 200);
    woods.shapes.rect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    woods.shapes.setColor(255, 255, 255, 10);
    woods.shapes.rect(300, 300, 50, 50);
woods.shapes.end();
Gdx.gl20.glBlendEquation(GL.GL_FUNC_ADD);
Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
```

This is what I am using for it right now, but I can't seem to get it right, the results are never what I am expecting. I suspect it has something to do with my blendfunc or blendequation but I have tried tons of different combinations to no avail. Any help at all would be fantastic.

Comment: Instead of using alpha blending you could try using stencil testing. You would render the cutout shapes first into the stencil buffer and then draw the black square with stencil testing enabled so that only the parts that don't have a cutout shape already drawn appear black.

Comment: Please only use the JOGL tag if and only if you use the JOGL backend of LibGDX, otherwise remove it from your question.

Comment: I kinda assumed any type you used opengl in Java it was considered java? Also I have considered stencil blending but it appears that it does not support transparency.